# is_file and file_exists are case insensitive on a mounted volumne

Tags: php, docker, filesystems

I have a docker container running debian with PHP 5.6 as a dev enviornment. The code is mounted from my Win10 host. I noticed today that both file_exists and is_file are case insensitive in the mounted directory. Both `is_file("/some/path/test.php")` and `is_file("/some/path/Test.php")` return true. On a Windows machine this is expected behaviour, but not on Linux. I want to avoid changing the code just to accomodate for my specific dev enviornment.

Is there a way to setup docker or PHP to emulate the behaviour of a real Linux machine without the mounted volume?

Answer (score -1):

`realpath($filePath)` will probably help:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

So essentially you could use

```
$resolvedPath = realpath($myPath);
if (is_file($resolvedPath)) {...}
```

Although I'm now uncertain this has actually answered your question. If your files are always well-formed for Linux, they're also going to work on Windows? Or are you planning to have two different files called `Test.php` and `test.php` in the same folder/directory, and need that difference to be recognised?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tested realpath and it just returns the filename in the same case you put it in. I will only ever have Test.php and in production it only has to run on Linux, but I run into all kinds of issues on my dev system because test.php "exists" even though it doesnt